# If $0$ of a topological ring $A$ is closed then $A$ is hausdorff.

Tags: general-topology

If $0$ of a topological ring $A$ is closed then $A$ is hausdorff.

Following is the proof which I have got:

If $x$ and $y$ are distinct elements of $A$, let $V$ be neighbourhood of $y-x$ which does not contain $0$ of $A$, and let $U=x-y+V$. Then $U$ is neighbourhood of $0$ such that $x-y\notin U$. Let $W$ be another neighbourhood of $0$ such that $W-W\in U$; then $x+W$ and $y+W$ are disjoint neighbourhoods of $x$ and $y$.

But I am not able to find where closeness of $0$ is used.

Answer (score 1):

First use the fact that $\{0\}$ is closed to show that $\{x\}$ is closed for each $x\in A$; this implies that $A$ is $T_1$. Every topological group is a uniform space and therefore completely regular, and a completely regular space is Tikhonov and therefore Hausdorff.

Comment: So we can forget the multiplication and keep only addition and prove this for a topological group.  Need not be Abelian.